# Google Chart API: Is it possible to have an incomplete chart?

Tags: graph, google-visualization

I need to make a chart showing weekly activity for the current week, with each day of the week as a point on the X axis.  Example:

[image]

This works fine, but the problem I'm having is that, if today were wednesday, there's no data for Thursday-Saturday.  Currently the chart depicts this by sending the line back to 0.  Is there any way to make Google Charts stop drawing the line at a specific point and leave the other data points empty?

I tried omitting the missing values from the dataset, but that just causes it to stretch Sunday-Wednesday across the entire graph.

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass the value `null`, which is Javascript's way of saying `nil`. Make sure you don't include quotation marks.

For instance:

```
["Sat", null, 165, 210]
```